# Can a low energetic photon be reflected?

Tags: photons, electrons, reflection

What happens to a photon that doesnt exceed any electron's binding energy in the atoms of a solid, when it hits given solid? How would it interact with the atoms in given solid?

Comment: For a metal, conduction band electrons near the Fermi surface have available empty states to be excited into that are infinitesimally higher in energy. Solids and atoms are different things.

Comment: @JonCuster in order for the photon to be absorbed both energy and momentum must be conserved so instead of a band diagram you should better use the band structure instead.

Comment: @JunSeo-He - I'm not quite sure what you are questioning - the Fermi surface is a 3D entity in (E,$k$) space so it holds both E and $k$.

Comment: The sensing dipoles in my UHF antenna are backed by a reflecting metal grid.

Answer (score 1):

A solid material may have nearly-free electrons which will respond to
the electric field of any photon.   Mirrors reflect because
of an aluminum or silver layer.   Window glass is transparent
because it lacks conduction electrons like a metal, but there
is still somewhat of a reflection possible, because every atom
has the potential to respond to an electric field ([Stark effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect)
and/or the magnetic field (Zeeman effect) which comprise a
photon.

It's a little more  complicated for a crystal with spacing comparable
to the photon wavelength, or an oilslick, or a  semiconductor, but... well,
all the complicated photon interactions is what makes our visual
experience so rich; when you see a rainbow, enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Ionization is not the only process by which light can interact with matter.
For example if you consider a crystalline solid, a photon can excite a collective vibrational mode (this is called a [phonon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon) and has the same energy levels of the quantum harmonic oscillator), thus a low energetic photon can excite a low frequency vibrational mode. Note that not all frequencies are allowed (in particular there is an upper limit to it), but low frequencies are always allowed.

Some other processes, instead do not occur at low energy. You mentioned ionization, but diffraction is another example. Diffraction in crystalline solids follow [Bragg's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law):

$n\lambda =2d \cdot sin\theta \quad$ where $n\in\mathbb N$ is the order of diffraction

You can see immediately that if $\lambda > 2d$ you do not get diffraction (of any order).

Answer (score 0):

When a photon hits a solid the photon gets absorbed only by valence electrons if there are available energy-momentum states available(not occupied)which have the same momentum and energy with the electron and the photon seperately.